# Meld failed while installing cassandra on node

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

I am trying to install Cassandra from LCM to new DC. But getting below error altough we have added private key.

```
2018-03-27 14:19:58,913 [opscenterd] ERROR: Meld failed on name="cassandra-6" ssh-management-address="cassandra-ip" node-id="f5344ce4-a0cc-4b49-ac0b-ae121bcabc63" node-name="cassandra-6" job-id="5fe313ed-f746-41cc-82bc-9f3166eae56b" stdout="Meld has started...

Meld failed on name="cassandra-6" ssh-management-address="cassandra-node-public-ip" node-id="f5344ce4-a0cc-4b49-ac0b-ae121bcabc63" node-name="cassandra-6" job-id="5fe313ed-f746-41cc-82bc-9f3166eae56b" stdout="Meld has started... HTTPConnectionPool(host='LCMIP', port=8888): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/lcm/internal/nodes/f5344ce4-a0cc-4b49-ac0b-ae121bcabc63/status (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x2cc9610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host',)) event-resource=http://LCMIP:8888/api/v1/lcm/internal/nodes/f5344ce4-a0cc-4b49-ac0b-ae121bcabc63/status2018-03-27 14:19:58,262 - opsc-meld - ERROR - HTTPConnectionPool(host='LCMIP', port=8888): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/lcm/internal/nodes/f5344ce4-a0cc-4b49-ac0b-ae121bcabc63/status (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x2cc9610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host',)) event-resource=http://LCMIP:8888/api/v1/lcm/internal/nodes/f5344ce4-a0cc-4b49-ac0b-ae121bcabc63/status " stderr=""
```

I have also tried with ssh credentials but it also did not work out.

```
LCM version: OpsCenter 6.1.6 
OS: centos 7
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is reported in your log: `Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host`.  I think that you need to check that destination node is running, and also firewall on both OpsCenter server & destination host.

Comment: I am able to telnet. Trying IP...Connected to IP. Escape character is '^]'. SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4

Comment: I solved connection issue. Now getting Received an HTTP 401 Unauthorized response while attempting to access the package repository. Check your repository credentials. I am able to login with same credentials on your official.

Comment: Did you correctly configure the repository, like described here? https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-opscenter/opsc/LCM/opscLCMcreateRepoCreds.html

Comment: Yes I follow the same instruction as on https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-opscenter/opsc/LCM/opscLCMcreateRepoCreds.html .

Comment: Authorization issue also solved but not getting error on dse start
ERROR [main] 2018-03-27 18:52:50,590  CassandraDaemon.java:705 - Exception encountered during startup

Comment: for that there more logs required. But it's better to ask this as another question...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167674/discussion-between-ranjeet-ranjan-and-alex-ott).

Comment: Can you please answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49527635/stop-cassandra-update-automatically