# Stop Cassandra update automatically

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

Please help me how I can **stop Cassandra update automatically?**

At present when I install Cassandra through opscentre I get an error.

```
Unable to restart DSE service. See /var/log/cassandra/system.log and /var/log/cassandra/output.log on the target node for details.
```

system.log

```
ERROR [main] 2018-03-28 07:58:26,123  CassandraDaemon.java:705 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils$Exporter.exportObject(Ljava/rmi/Remote;ILjava/rmi/server/RMIClientSocketFactory;Ljava/rmi/server/RMIServerSocketFactory;Lsun/misc/ObjectInputFilter;)Ljava/rmi/Remote;
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:150) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:135) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:405) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils.createJMXServer(JMXServerUtils.java:104) ~[cassandra-all-3.10.0.1652.jar:3.10.0.1652]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.maybeInitJmx(CassandraDaemon.java:143) ~[cassandra-all-3.10.0.1652.jar:3.10.0.1652]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:188) ~[cassandra-all-3.10.0.1652.jar:3.10.0.1652]
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:471) ~[dse-core-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:599) ~[cassandra-all-3.10.0.1652.jar:3.10.0.1652]
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:93) [dse-core-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
```

But when I update my OS with the command `**yum update**`, it updates DSE 5.1.0 to 5.1.7. After updating dse start. I am not able to understand why its happening? 
On other node dse 5.1 working perfectly.

```
OS: centos 7
```

Comment: Did you check system.log? Anything interesting?

Comment: Error updated in question.

Comment: What java version are you using? you might be running into this issue. Check the following two links https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcassandra%5D+14173 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14173

Comment: We are not installing any java from ourself. I think DSE installing JAVA automatically? Do we need to install java prior to installing Cassandra?

Comment: Java is somehow updated on that machine. DSE requires Java preinstalled, not install itself

Comment: I have installed java before installing dse but still getting the same error.

Comment: It's the wrong version of java. 8u162 breaks dse.

Comment: Which version of java do you recommend?

Comment: If I check opscenter job id I can see: Java version 1.8.0_161 found, installing version 1.8.0_162. It means Opscentre installing java automatically.

Comment: the latest DSE 5.1 should have the fix for that Java JMX compatibility problem. But your message says that it's still dse-core-5.1.0

Comment: I did not understand what you trying to say. Please let me know what I need to do so that problem gets solved?

Comment: I wanted to use 5.1.0 only as we are already using 2 node cluster of dse 5.1.0. Please guide me.

Comment: @RanjeetRanjan If you want to to prevent your CentOS from upgrading to latest DSE from 5.1.0, please use `yum versionlock`: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/98873. Although it's generally recommended to upgrade to latest patch release of DSE.  If you still have problems, feel free to reach me at https://academy.datastax.com/slack

Comment: Alex I already requested for slack long time but did not get approval. Again I am getting error http://myemail:password@rpm.datastax.com/enterprise/noarch/dse-libtomcat-5.1.5-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized             ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA